# Lengthening Thermistor Leads with Different Gauge Wire

Tags: thermistor

I have a NTC thermistor with 30 AWG leads (TDK B57703M series) and wanted to lengthen these. Would it work correctly if I soldered 26 AWG wire to the leads? I know different gauges can mess with resistances and attenuation, so I wanted to confirm if this would be ok or not.

Comment: You should say what length of extension you want to add. A few cm would be fine in most gauges. 100 metres would be quite different. You want length = ???

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Only a few centimeters more, so I should be ok. Though say I wanted to add a half meter of length, what issues would I face?

Comment: See others' answers. A potential for some noise input - use twisted pair and probably OK in some cases. The higher the thermistor resistance the more potential for noise coupling (as stray capacitive coupling impedance is a greater % of thermistor impedance.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extending the leads with almost the same wire gauge would be fine. That part number offers only a 10K or 30K (at room temperature, or 25 deg C) option. The wires resistance is too small to be a factor here, unless it has to run several feet or more.
 Even then the main issue would be noise pickup, so you would need to use shielded cable and RCL filters before you send the signal to an op-amp for amplification and scaling. These thermistors do not respond to temperature changes quickly, so a low-pass filter of 10HZ would be fine.

Comment: Extending the leads with vastly different gauge would also be fine, though maybe trickier to solder.

Comment: @Sparky256 if I don't need very exact measurements, wouldn't using a 10 kOhm resistor for a voltage divider work.

Comment: @AlexD. Funny you should ask. I used a stable 5.00 vdc supply to feed a 10K NTC thermistor, which had a 10K 0.1% resistor in series to ground. This meant that at room temperature (25 deg C) I had 2.50 volts at this junction. I multiplied by 10 (in software) to get 25.0 deg C, then x 1.8 + 32 (in software) to get deg F. If the temperature rose so did the readings. It was not very linear or accurate at extreme ranges but served its purpose, which was to measure ambient, transformer and mosfet temperatures.

Comment: @Sparky256 I've got it working great now, and using a setup similar to what you listed, however I'm not assuming linearity. I'm using a simplified version of the Steinhart–Hart equation which is a model of the resistance of a semiconductor at different temperatures. It's what I have found from a lot of sources I should use for thermistors. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhart%E2%80%93Hart_equation

Comment: @AlexD. That is good to know, because as temperature rises it cannot put more than 5 volts at the 10K junction. When in ice-water the reading stops at 0.0 volts, so without corrections your limited to 25 deg C +/- 15 deg at most.